# Objective c - Getting text from a UITextfield after keyboard is dismissed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

Another NEWBIE QUESTION:

I'm feeling pretty dumb right now.  I haven't worked with UI text input for a very long time.  So this is what I have so far.  I have a view with a subview.  I've wired up my IBOutlets for the UITextFields and I've wired the text fields back to the main view controller file owner for the delegate (not sure about that one).  I happily build and run.  I enter some text and when I click outside the text field my keyboard goes away.  But when I exit my view I should be saving the values in each of the fields.  But when I step through the code, my textfields (not the text but the fields themselves) are all nil.

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, obviously I've missed an important step here.

Calling saveUserSettings from the main view when user clicks to close the subview:

```
- (IBAction)closeButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.userSettingsView saveUserSettings];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The psychedelic colors are helping me see them during development.  :-)

The selected view is a scrollview but it's not scrolling either.  That's a different issue.

[image]

Here is the IDUtilityViewController code:

```
@interface IDUtilityViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet IDAboutView *aboutView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet IDUserSettingsView *userSettingsView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *aboutButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *userSettingsButton;

@end

@implementation IDUtilityViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.aboutView = [[IDAboutView alloc] init];
    self.userSettingsView = [[IDUserSettingsView alloc] init];
    [self userSettingsButtonPressed:self.userSettingsButton];

    UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

- (void)hideKeyboard
{
    [self.userSettingsView saveUserSettings];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

#pragma mark - IBActions

- (IBAction)closeButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    //[self.userSettingsView saveUserSettings];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)aboutButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.userSettingsView.hidden = YES;
    self.aboutView.hidden = NO;
}

- (IBAction)userSettingsButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.aboutView.hidden = YES;
    self.userSettingsView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Here is the IDUserSettingsView.h:

```
@interface IDUserSettingsView : UIView 
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *userIDField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *ipAddressField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *portNumberField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *doorNameField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *badgeNumberField;

- (void)saveUserSettings;

@end
```

Here is the IDUserSettingsView.m:

```
#import "IDUserSettingsView.h"

@interface IDUserSettingsView()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults;
@end

@implementation IDUserSettingsView

@synthesize userIDField = _userIDField;
@synthesize passwordField = _passwordField;
@synthesize ipAddressField = _ipAddressField;
@synthesize portNumberField = _portNumberField;
@synthesize doorNameField = _doorNameField;
@synthesize badgeNumberField = _badgeNumberField;

NSMutableString *emptyString = @"";

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)saveUserSettings
{
    [self.standardUserDefaults setObject:self.userIDField.text forKey:@"isonos_userID"];
    [self.standardUserDefaults setObject:self.passwordField.text forKey:@"isonos_password"];
    [self.standardUserDefaults setObject:self.ipAddressField.text forKey:@"isonos_ipAddress"];
    [self.standardUserDefaults setObject:self.portNumberField.text forKey:@"isonos_portNumber"];
    [self.standardUserDefaults setObject:self.doorNameField.text forKey:@"isonos_doorName"];
    [self.standardUserDefaults setObject:self.badgeNumberField.text forKey:@"isonos_badgeNumber"];
}

- (UITextField *)userIDField {
    return _userIDField;
}

- (void)setUserIDField:(UITextField *)userIDField {
    NSString *result = [self.standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"isonos_userID"];
    if (!result) result = emptyString;
    _userIDField.text = [emptyString stringByAppendingString:result];
}

- (UITextField *)passwordField {
    return _passwordField;
}

- (void)setPasswordField:(UITextField *)passwordField {
    NSString *result = [self.standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"isonos_password"];
    if (!result) result = emptyString;
    _passwordField.text = [emptyString stringByAppendingString:result];
}

- (UITextField *)ipAddressField {
    return _ipAddressField;
}

- (void)setIpAddressField:(UITextField *)ipAddressField {
    NSString *result = [self.standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"isonos_ipAddress"];
    if (!result) result = emptyString;
    _ipAddressField.text = [emptyString stringByAppendingString:result];
}

- (UITextField *)portNumberField {
    return _portNumberField;
}

- (void)setPortNumberField:(UITextField *)portNumberField {
    NSString *result = [self.standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"isonos_portNumber"];
    if (!result) result = emptyString;
    _portNumberField.text = [emptyString stringByAppendingString:result];
}

- (UITextField *)doorNameField {
    return _doorNameField;
}

- (void)setDoorNameField:(UITextField *)doorNameField {
    NSString *result = [self.standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"isonos_doorName"];
    if (!result) result = emptyString;
    _doorNameField.text = [emptyString stringByAppendingString:result];
}

- (UITextField *)badgeNumberField {
    return _badgeNumberField;
}

- (void)setBadgeNumberField:(UITextField *)badgeNumberField {
    NSString *result = [self.standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"isonos_badgeNumber"];
    if (!result) result = emptyString;
    _badgeNumberField.text = [emptyString stringByAppendingString:result];
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

I've even tried just setting the controls straight with no values:

```
#import "IDUserSettingsView.h"

@interface IDUserSettingsView()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults;
@end

@implementation IDUserSettingsView

@synthesize userIDField = _userIDField;
@synthesize passwordField = _passwordField;
@synthesize ipAddressField = _ipAddressField;
@synthesize portNumberField = _portNumberField;
@synthesize doorNameField = _doorNameField;
@synthesize badgeNumberField = _badgeNumberField;

NSMutableString *emptyString = @"";

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)saveUserSettings
{
    [self.standardUserDefaults setObject:self.userIDField.text forKey:@"isonos_userID"];
    [self.standardUserDefaults setObject:self.passwordField.text forKey:@"isonos_password"];
    [self.standardUserDefaults setObject:self.ipAddressField.text forKey:@"isonos_ipAddress"];
    [self.standardUserDefaults setObject:self.portNumberField.text forKey:@"isonos_portNumber"];
    [self.standardUserDefaults setObject:self.doorNameField.text forKey:@"isonos_doorName"];
    [self.standardUserDefaults setObject:self.badgeNumberField.text forKey:@"isonos_badgeNumber"];
}

- (UITextField *)userIDField {
    return _userIDField;
}

- (void)setUserIDField:(UITextField *)userIDField {
    _userIDField = userIDField; // breakpoint here
}

- (UITextField *)passwordField {
    return _passwordField;
}

- (void)setPasswordField:(UITextField *)passwordField {
    _passwordField = passwordField;
}

- (UITextField *)ipAddressField {
    return _ipAddressField;
}

- (void)setIpAddressField:(UITextField *)ipAddressField {
    _ipAddressField = ipAddressField;
}

- (UITextField *)portNumberField {
    return _portNumberField;
}

- (void)setPortNumberField:(UITextField *)portNumberField {
    _portNumberField = portNumberField;
}

- (UITextField *)doorNameField {
    return _doorNameField;
}

- (void)setDoorNameField:(UITextField *)doorNameField {
    _doorNameField = doorNameField;
}

- (UITextField *)badgeNumberField {
    return _badgeNumberField;
}

- (void)setBadgeNumberField:(UITextField *)badgeNumberField {
    _badgeNumberField = badgeNumberField;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Here is the View Hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: *where* are you calling your "`saveUserSettings`" method from?

Comment: Where exactly is saveUserSettings being called?

Comment: @HermannKlecker shouldn't matter, if he's able to step through it in the debugger it is being called.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann - from the closeButtonPressed IBAction method on the main view.  I'll add to my question for you.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert, it does matter. They could be nil in dealloc. And they could be nil if they are called on any new instance of the same class - we have seen lots of examples of this on SO. And they could be nil if the method is invoked from outside the object hile the instance is still alive but the view has been destroied already. Lots of chanes for making mistakes.

Comment: Perhaps. It doesn't sound like it to me though, from the description so far. Lucy see my updated answer for some changes you could make to try and debug this.

Comment: Lucy, which control/button invokes closeButtonPressed: ? Could it be that it is called from somewhere else too?

Comment: As for the scroll view. It does not scroll where there isn't anything to scroll. The content view must be larger than the scrollview itself. If you want it to be scrollable when the keyboard hides some of the text views, then you need to extend the content view at its bottom by that amount of space, that you want the scroll view to be scrolled up as maximum. If that does not fix it then better raise a separate question for that.

Comment: Also from past experience I wouldn't use a scroll view here... I'd use a UITableView and make each field a row in the table view, with custom cells, each with a textfield inside. But don't do that unless you have plenty of time on your hands... it's complicated.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert - The plan is to use a UITableView, but for expediency I was trying to just use text boxes (that plan didn't work out to be so fast).

Comment: @AbhiBeckert - Yeah, the scroll view is only for when the view is in landscape.  Anyway, I'll deal with that after I get the text from my fields.

Comment: Try recreating the outlets. If that doesn't work, can you post the code? Or perhaps even try re-creating the entire xib.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert - I tried recreating all new outlets.  Now I've posted the code.  This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling "`saveUserSettings`" from your main view (and *not* your IDUserSettingsView), then it's likely the IDUserSettingsView has dismissed and all the outlet connections are long gone.

Why not copy the changed settings into some structure that gets sent/copied into your main view which you can then call "`saveUserSettings`" on when the user chooses to update his/her settings?

Or, make certain "`saveUserSettings`" gets called ***before*** your IDUserSettingsView dismisses (and everything in that view gets torn down and/or dealloc'd).

Comment: He's told ARC to make them strong references, so it shouldn't be released even if the view goes away?

Comment: You're onto something here.  I created a dummy project and put everything into one view and it worked.  I moved my saveUserSettings to execute whenever the keyboard is dismissed.  So I know it is getting called while the IDUserSettingsView is still open.  Yet I seem to not have my pointer to my text fields.  This is driving me crazy.  I'm posting some code.

Comment: I have a feeling you might have ***TWO*** "`userSettingsView`" objects going on.  What happens if you take the "`    self.userSettingsView = [[IDUserSettingsView alloc] init];`" line out of your "`viewDidLoad`" method? It's still defined in a storyboard or XIB file and still set to an outlet right?

Answer (score 1):

You probably messed up the `IBOutlet` connections, I bet they're not connected or connected to the wrong objects.

Try defining a setter method and putting a breakpoint on it to try and find where it's being set or perhaps cleared to `nil`:

```
- (void)setUserIDField:(UITextField *)field
{
    _userIDField = field; // breakpoint here
}
```

(note: if you have ARC disabled you will need to retain the new value and release the old value).

Comment: See the filled circles next to the lines to the left. If they were not connected at all, then the circles were empty.